# Pass by value and pass by reference in Assembly

Tags: assembly, parameters, dos, masm, x86-16

I'm trying to solve this problem:

Create a *PROC* procedure that takes one parameter as *Pass by Value* and prints the number of 'X' according to the number passed as a parameter.  **Before printing, make sure parameter is a positive number, at end of program you need to change the registers that have been used back to their first values**.

If the input to the procedure is 5 then the output on the console should be:

> XXXXX

This is my code:

```
var db 5 ;In the dataseg  
push [var] ;in the codeseg  

proc example  
    pop cx  
    cmp cx,0  
    ja print  
print:  
    mov dl, 'X'  
    mov ah, 2h  
    int 21h  
    loop print  
    ret  
endp example
```

Will this code work as expected, and if not, why? How can it be fixed?

Comment: There's no `PUSH r/m8`, so you should declare your `var` using `dw` (or `dd`). And you should also make it explicit how many bytes you want to push by using `push word ptr [var]` (or `dword ptr`).

Comment: Are you required to pass parameters on the stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, your code is seriously broken.

Functions access their args from the stack with stuff like `mov ecx, [esp+4]`.  Or in 16bit code, `[sp+2]` isn't an encodable addressing mode, so you should make a stack frame:
 `push bp` / `mov bp, sp` / `mov cx, [bp+4]`.  (And undo this at the end of the function).  Google "stack frame" for more about this, and how x86 functions access their args on the stack.  (Or see the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki).

This is assuming you need to pass args on the stack.  Some calling conventions pass the first couple args in registers, which saves instructions esp. in small functions.

---

Your function ends with `ret`, which means you're assuming you were called with a `call`.  The return address will be at `[sp]` (or `[esp]` in 32bit code) on function entry.  A `pop` at that point will load the return address.  If an interrupt comes in while the return address is below `sp`, it will be overwritten, so it's not safe to `pop` and then adjust `sp` back down again before `ret`.

Pushing an arg and then falling through into a function is not good practice.

---

Your branch is also wrong:

```
    cmp cx, 0
    ja print  
print:         ; execution ends up here whether the branch is taken or not
```

Using `ja` means you're treating your arg as unsigned.  That's fine, since it's still possible for it to be non-positive by being zero.  However, I think the assignment was intending you to treat the arg as signed.  Try something like `jle  nonpositive`, and put `nonpositive:` somewhere useful.

---

The [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki has some links to tutorials and reference material.   With that + a debugger + google, you should be able to answer your own questions.

Comment: OP is using 16-bit code. Some of your answer may make it confusing since it discusses 32-bit code. ie: `[esp]`, `mov ecx, [esp+4]` . As well the syntax in OP's code is MASM/TASM.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I didn't want to write `[sp+4]` (or `[sp+2]`?) because that's not a legal effective address.  I didn't want to spend more time giving a better answer, or droning on about how 16bit is dumb.  Did I write anything that isn't valid MASM syntax?  Does it not use `.local_label`s?

Comment: As for the syntax, you can add a period to the beginning of a MASM/TASM label but it isn't treated as a local. You need to add the `LOCALS` directive to the top of the assembler file and then prepend the labels with `@@`

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I never said the question was off-topic for SO, just that I wasn't interested in that part of it.  It was in dire need of an edit, though, and I did want to leave some kind of reply about popping to access args.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I updated my answer, since you're right it's not good for SO to have low-quality answers sitting around.

Answer (score 3):

As an addendum to Peter's answer you can use MASM/TASM to generate the prologue and epilogue code to set up *BP* for you, and allow you to access procedure/function arguments by label. A reasonably good tutorial about PROC subroutines used by MASM and TASM can be found [here](http://www.oocities.org/codeteacher/x86asm/asml1010.html)

I've also changed `var` to be a *WORD*  instead of a *BYTE*. The resulting code looks like:

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100H

.DATA
    var dw 5           ; Change to 16-bit WORD

.CODE

example proc C         ; C Calling convention - parameters on stack right to left
    ARG num:WORD       ; We take one argument called `num` that is a word

    mov cx, num        ; Move the 16-bit value in `num` to CX counter
                       ;     same as: mov cx, [bp+4]
                       ;     [bp+0] is saved copy of BP put on stack by MASM's prologue
                       ;     [bp+2] return address placed on stack by CALL
    cmp cx, 0
    jle negative       ; If we are less than or equal to 0, exit procedure
    mov dl, 'X'
    mov ah, 2h         ; ah and dl not destroyed by int 21h/ah=2 so set them once
                       ;     before loop
print:
    int 21h            ; Print an 'X'
    loop print         ; Continue until loop is 0
negative:
    ret
endp example

main proc
     mov ax, @data     ; initialize DS
     mov ds, ax

     push [var]        ; Push 2-byte value at `var` (pushing by value)
     call example
     add sp, 2         ; Remove parameter from stack
                       ;     Not necessary since we use int 21h to exit right after
     mov ah, 4ch       ; return control to DOS
     int 21h
main endp

end main               ; Entry point = label main
```

The code above would have generated these instructions for the procedure `example`:

```
example proc
    push bp            ; Save BP on stack  \
    mov bp, sp         ; Set BP to SP      / Function prologue
                       ;     [bp+0] is saved copy of BP put on stack by prologue
                       ;     [bp+2] return address placed on stack by CALL
                       ;     [bp+4] first parameter (NUM)

    mov cx, [bp+4]     ; Move the value at BP+4 (NUM) to CX counter

    cmp cx, 0
    jle negative       ; If we are less than or equal to 0, exit procedure
    mov dl, 'X'
    mov ah, 2h         ; ah and dl not destroyed by int 21h/ah=2 so set them once
                       ;     before loop
print:
    int 21h            ; Print an 'X'
    loop print         ; Continue until loop is 0
negative:
    mov sp, bp         ; Restore stack pointer \
    pop bp             ; Restore BP register   / Function epilogue
    ret
endp example
```

I leave it as an exercise to the reader to determine all the registers the `example` *PROC* changes, and saves/restores them as requested in the homework assignment. Hint: *PUSH* them after the *ARG* directive and *POP* them in reverse order just prior to the `RET`